# Count reads and writes in Stream

Tags: c#, .net

What is the correct way to count how much bytes Stream writes and reads ?
It is simple to derive from Stream and overload methods.
The issue is that any Read** method can call other Read** method and then I might count twice.
Is there a proper solution for this ?

Let's say I do wrapper for Stream, where should I increase the read and write count ?

```
    public class CountStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly Stream _stream;

        protected CountStream (Stream stream) => _stream = stream;

        public override object InitializeLifetimeService() => _stream.InitializeLifetimeService();

        public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object? state) => _stream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);

        public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object? state) => _stream.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);

        public override void Close()
        {
            _stream.Close();
        }

        public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) => _stream.EndRead(asyncResult);

        public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            _stream.EndWrite(asyncResult);
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            _stream.Flush();
        }

        public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => _stream.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        public override int Read(Span<byte> buffer) => _stream.Read(buffer);

        public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);

        public override ValueTask<int> ReadAsync(Memory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) => _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);

        public override int ReadByte() => _stream.ReadByte();

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => _stream.Seek(offset, origin);

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            _stream.SetLength(value);
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override void Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer)
        {
            _stream.Write(buffer);
        }

        public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => _stream.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);

        public override ValueTask WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) => _stream.WriteAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);

        public override void WriteByte(byte value)
        {
            _stream.WriteByte(value);
        }

        public override bool CanRead => _stream.CanRead;

        public override bool CanSeek => _stream.CanSeek;

        public override bool CanTimeout => _stream.CanTimeout;

        public override bool CanWrite => _stream.CanWrite;

        public override long Length => _stream.Length;

        public override long Position
        {
            get => _stream.Position;
            set => _stream.Position = value;
        }

        public override int ReadTimeout
        {
            get => _stream.ReadTimeout;
            set => _stream.ReadTimeout = value;
        }

        public override int WriteTimeout
        {
            get => _stream.WriteTimeout;
            set => _stream.WriteTimeout = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make your Stream overload embed an actual Stream object. As long as the functions in your own class don't call these other functions, nothing will counts twice if you pass all calls on to the non-counting actual functions on the stream object.

Comment: Show your simple derived class and how Read calls another Read method. You just have to keep count in one method that all other methods call.

Comment: Use BinaryReader.  Other streams use characters (one or two bytes) and depending on size of characters you will not get a corect byte count.

Comment: @jdweng no, streams don't magically switch from bytes to characters. As usual, you kind of have a point, but are missing it entirely. Yes, there are multibyte encodings, but that matters if you use a StreamReader and still want to count bytes. The OP here is talking about a Stream, which doesn't deal in characters.

Comment: @Nyerguds Added Stream derived class to the question. It simply delegates everything to the member. Where do I increase the counters ?

Comment: In _all of them._ Do not make _any_ functions there that handle reading or writing redirect to other functions in your own class. For _all_ of them, increase your counters, _then_ redirect them to the same function on `_stream`. So don't use that `=>` construct.

Comment: @Nyerguds for reads, you'd have to proxy then increment - to know how many the wrapped stream actually returned, but: yup, that

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah, point; requested bytes aren't guaranteed to be actually read bytes. I forgot about that.

Comment: @Nyerguds my concern is that it is possible that in new .NET , there will be a new Stream Read method which internally calls to other Read methods and then I can count one read twice.

Comment: If a new `Stream.Read()` overload gets added, it won't call your derived methods anyway, and callers won't call yours until you override it and recompile.

Comment: They're not gonna change the basic Stream interface, you know... it'd make all current Stream classes invalid as implementations of `Stream`. I'm honestly not sure what your concern is.